# Get match rate for two arrays of integers

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, match

I need to get the match rate of two arrays based in their values.

Let's say I have an array of `[9]` and another one of `[9]` my match rate would be 100%. If one array is `[9]` and the other is `[4]` the rate would be 50%. If array one is `[4, 3]` and array two is `[4,3]` the rate is 100%.

I am not quire sure on how to sole this in order to get the rate back. The values in the array are only between 0-9 and are always in order. So the first item of array one should be matched with the first item of array two etc.

I am using ruby (on rails) but I think the question is more generic.

Thank you!

Comment: I would expect the "match rate" of `[9]` and `[4]` to be 0%. Why is it 50%?

Comment: If the "match rate" of `[9]` and `[4]` is in fact 0% you could write `def match_rate(a1,a2);  (100.0/a1.size) * a1.zip(a2).count { |a1,a2| a1==a2 }; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sure but in this case the `9` and `4` represent a scale that goes from 0-9. That's why 9 and 9 matches 100%, 9 and 8 90% and 9 and 0 0%.

Comment: You need to edit the question to clarify that. While doing so I suggest you add more examples, showing the desired result for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the following.

```
def match_rate(a1,a2)
  100.0 - (10.0/a1.size) * a1.zip(a2).sum { |a1,a2| (a1-a2).abs }
end
```

```
match_rate([9], [9])                   #=> 100.0
match_rate([9], [4])                   #=>  50.0
match_rate([4,3], [4,3])               #=> 100.0
match_rate([4,3], [4,2])               #=>  95.0 
match_rate([4,3], [3,4])               #=>  90.0
match_rate([1,2,3,4,5], [1,-2,3,-4,5]) #=>  76.0
```

​
I've assumed that `a1` and `a2` are non-empty arrays of the same size. If desired, you could of course confirm that in the method.

See [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum).

Suppose

```
a1 = [4,6,2]
a2 = [7,6,5]
```

Then

```
a = 10.0/a1.size
  #=> 3.3333333333333335
b = a1.zip(a2)
  #=> [[4, 7], [6, 6], [2, 5]]
c = b.sum { |a1,a2| (a1-a2).abs }
  #=> 3 + 0 + 3 => 6
d = a * c
  #=> 20.0 
100.0 - d
  #=> 80.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't understand why `[9]` and `[4]` give `50%` but if `[9]` and `[4]` would return 0 than you can do it this way:

```rb
def arrays_rate(a, b)
  return 100 if a.empty? && b.empty?
  ((a & b).size.to_f / [a, b].map(&:size).max) * 100
end
```

```rb
a = [9]
b = [9]

arrays_rate(a, b)

# => 100
```

```rb
a = [9]
b = [4]

arrays_rate(a, b)

# => 0
```

```rb
a = [9, 4]
b = [4, 3]

arrays_rate(a, b)

# => 50
```

```rb
a = [9, 4, 1]
b = [4, 9, 2]


arrays_rate(a, b)

# => 66.6
```

```rb
a = [9, 4, 1]
b = [4, 9, 2, 5, 6]

arrays_rate(a, b)

# => 40
```